# Angularjs select option ng-change is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-select

I am using simple angularjs select option. Every thing is working fine but ng-change is not working.Any Specific reason ? I have tried with $watch with 'selectedParent' . But that is also not firing. So i guess option change is not happening. Any help why is it so ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12 n-p" ng-controller="PartStructureEditController">
    <div class="col-md-12 n-p pull-left">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="ToolDes">Parent Level / Part Number :</label><br />
            <select ng-options="object.combine as (object.Level + ' / ' + object.PartNo) for object in parentDropdown track by object.PartStructureId" ng-model="selectedParent"  ng-change="changeParent()" class="form-control">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    MyApp.controller('PartStructureEditController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 
       function ($rootScope, $scope) {
           function populateDropDown(data, ParentPartStructureId) {
               var result = [];
               data.map(function (a) {
                   if ((parseInt(a.ParentPartStructureId) !== ParentPartStructureId) || (parseInt(a.PartStructureId) !== ParentPartStructureId)) {
                       result.push(a);
                   }
               });
               $scope.parentDropdown = result;
               $scope.selectedParent = result[result.length - 1];
           }
           $scope.changeParent = function(){
                console.log('something');   
           }
       }]);
})();
```

Comment: I tested your code in a plnkr and it is working as intended. However, I am using different data, can you provide some example data that you use for your ng-options?

Comment: I debug this. It is not working because of <select ng-options="object.combine as (object.Level + ' / ' + object.PartNo) for object in parentDropdown track by object.PartStructureId"